# Open GL Bad Config Error on Samsung S4

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am getting the following error on Samsung S4

```
10-21 16:25:44.100: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 11320
10-21 16:25:44.100: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): Process: <bundle ID>, PID: 29778
10-21 16:25:44.100: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): java.lang.RuntimeException: createContext failed: EGL_BAD_CONFIG
10-21 16:25:44.100: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1201)
10-21 16:25:44.100: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1192)
10-21 16:25:44.100: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1042)
10-21 16:25:44.100: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1409)
10-21 16:25:44.100: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

The error is because of :

```
this.setEGLContextFactory(new MyDefaultContextFactory());
this.setEGLConfigChooser(GL_RED_SIZE, GL_GREEN_SIZE, GL_BLUE_SIZE, GL_ALPHA_SIZE,
        GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 0);//<-this line
this.setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR
        | GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS);
this.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
this.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
```

Where the configuration passed is : 8,8,8,8,24

Moving the above line at the end works though. Whats the reason for this?

PS: The code works fine on Nexus5 or MotoG in either case.
All devices running Kitkat 4.4.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see it clearly specified in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html), but from looking at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/opengl/java/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.java) of `GLSurfaceView`, it really appears to be the case that `setEGLContextClientVersion()` must be called **before** `setEGLConfigChooser()`.

Not copying any code because I'm not sure if that would violate copyrights, but you can follow along if you pull up the code link above:

1. The overload of `setEGLContextChooser()` used in your code instantiates a new `ComponentSizeChoser`, with the specified sizes passed to the constructor.
2. The constructor of `ComponentSizeChooser` invokes the base class constructor, passing the specified sizes packed into a config spec to the base constructor. The base class is `BaseConfigChooser`.
3. The constructor of `BaseConfigChooser` invokes a private method `filterConfigSpec()`, passing it the config spec,
4. `filterConfigSpec()` looks at the value of the `mEGLContextClientVersion` member variable, and uses it to determine the value of the `EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE` attribute, which it adds to the config spec. It then returns the config spec with this additional attribute.
5. Back in the `BaseConfigChooser` constructor, the modified config spec is assigned to a member variable.
6. The config spec in this member variable is used later when the `chooseConfig()` method is called, where the actual configuration is selected.

`mEGLContextClientVersion` is the value set by `setEGLContextClientVersion()`. Therefore, the value set with this method will only be included in the configuration selection if `setEGLContextClientVersion()` is called before `setEGLContextChooser()`.

Some devices provide configs that support both ES 1.X and ES 2.0/3.0, while others provide separate configs for 1.X and 2.0/3.0 support. This is most likely why the context creation succeeds with the calls in the "wrong" order on some devices, while it fails on others.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helps a lot. However, there is a spell error -- "1. The overload of `setEGLContextChooser()`" should be `setEGLConfigChooser`.