# OpenGL app crashes when using setEGLConfigChooser on Zenfone Deluxe 2

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

I have an Android application that uses a `GLSurfaceView` for rendering. The application works on all our devices except one: Our Zenfone Deluxe 2. In our `GLSurfaceView` constructor I do

```
setEGLConfigChooser(
    8, 8, 8, 8, // rgba
    24,         // depth
    8);         // stencil
```

This always works except for the Zenfone Deluxe 2 where it crashes, giving the following stack trace:

```
10-13 10:37:07.975 10066-10066/com.my.company.demo V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.my.company.demo
10-13 10:37:07.975 10066-10066/com.my.company.demo V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
10-13 10:37:08.045 10066-10066/com.my.company.demo W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
10-13 10:37:08.065 10066-10066/com.my.company.demo V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.my.company.demo
10-13 10:37:08.065 10066-10066/com.my.company.demo V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
10-13 10:37:08.335 10066-10107/com.my.company.demo D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-13 10:37:08.405 10066-10107/com.my.company.demo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-13 10:37:08.405 10066-10107/com.my.company.demo W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
10-13 10:37:08.415 10066-10105/com.my.company.demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1298
    Process: com.my.company.demo, PID: 10066
    java.lang.RuntimeException: createContext failed: EGL_BAD_CONFIG
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1196)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1187)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1037)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1404)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1243)
```

So then I simply uncommented the call to `setEGLConfigChooser` and then the application runs fine. OpenGL then gives me `(8, 8, 8, 0)` for RGBA, `24` for the depth buffer and `8` for the stencil buffer. Ok, so then I set these values in the `setEGLConfigChooser` instead, but then the app still crashes with the same output.

I am not sure what to make of this or how to solve it. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setEGLConfigChooser(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) for `setEGLConfigChooser` states

> Install a config chooser which will choose a config with at least the specified depthSize and stencilSize, and exactly the specified redSize, greenSize, blueSize and alphaSize.
>
> If this method is called, it must be called before setRenderer(Renderer) is called.
>
> If no setEGLConfigChooser method is called, then by default the view will choose an RGB_888 surface with a depth buffer depth of at least 16 bits.

which does not help much in this issue. What can be the issue? I would very much like to be able to call `setEGLConfigChooser` in a more generic way to target all devices.

**More device info:**

The Zenfone Deluxe 2 is an x86 device with a PowerVR Rogue G6430 GPU. I have downloaded and installed the latest software updates possible.

- `gl10.glGetString(GL10.GL_VENDOR);` gives `"Imagination Technologies"`
- `gl10.glGetString(GL10.GL_RENDERER);` gives `"PowerVR Rogue G6430"`
- `gl10.glGetString(GL10.GL_VERSION);` gives `"OpenGL ES 3.1 build 1.5@3830101"`
- `gl10.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS);` gives

  ```
  GL_EXT_debug_marker
  GL_EXT_blend_minmax
  GL_EXT_color_buffer_float
  GL_EXT_copy_image
  GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
  GL_EXT_draw_buffers
  GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed
  GL_EXT_geometry_shader
  GL_EXT_geometry_point_size
  GL_EXT_gpu_shader5
  GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
  GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture
  GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean
  GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box
  GL_EXT_pvrtc_sRGB
  GL_EXT_read_format_bgra
  GL_EXT_robustness
  GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects
  GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch
  GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks
  GL_EXT_shader_pixel_local_storage
  GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod
  GL_EXT_shadow_samplers
  GL_EXT_tessellation_shader
  GL_EXT_tessellation_point_size
  GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp
  GL_EXT_texture_buffer
  GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array
  GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
  GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
  GL_EXT_texture_rg
  GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode
  GL_IMG_multisampled_render_to_texture
  GL_IMG_program_binary
  GL_IMG_read_format
  GL_IMG_shader_binary
  GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
  GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc2
  GL_IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888
  GL_IMG_texture_npot
  GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
  GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
  GL_KHR_debug
  GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
  GL_OES_depth24
  GL_OES_depth_texture
  GL_OES_EGL_image
  GL_OES_EGL_image_external
  GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3
  GL_OES_EGL_sync
  GL_OES_element_index_uint
  GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
  GL_OES_draw_buffers_indexed
  GL_OES_get_program_binary
  GL_OES_mapbuffer
  GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
  GL_OES_required_internalformat
  GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
  GL_OES_sample_shading
  GL_OES_sample_variables
  GL_OES_shader_image_atomic
  GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation
  GL_OES_standard_derivatives
  GL_OES_surfaceless_context
  GL_OES_texture_float
  GL_OES_texture_half_float
  GL_OES_texture_npot
  GL_OES_texture_stencil8
  GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array
  GL_OES_vertex_array_object
  GL_OES_vertex_half_float
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it crashes is because I called `setEGLConfigChooser()` *before* `setEGLContextClientVersion()`. Moving the call after removes the crash and it still works on other devices. More information about why it crashes can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26522689/1139324) answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the good old [MultisampleConfigChooser](https://github.com/hjanetzek/GLMap/blob/master/project/src/com/android/glmap/MultisampleConfigChooser.java), the depth is only 16 bits and the stencil is only 1. Also, after cycling through the [EGL 1.4 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/specs/eglspec.1.4.pdf), I did not find any statement regarding the minimum supported stencil, depth and color buffer sizes.

You can try it with lower numbers, but you might need to make it more complex if you want to choose the best one available.

Comment: My problem isn't about which values to choose, it is about crashing in `setEGLConfigChooser` for one specific device, while all other of my devices works when calling it. It also crashes when using the exact same config that the device gives me when not calling `setEGLConfigChooser`.

Comment: EGL_BAD_CONFIG definitely means the crash is caused because the configuration you passed in was not right. So it means you have to be careful which values you can choose.